# Help for one simple diagram about genetic algorithmic

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would like to produce the following diagram.

[image]

Thanks to the following comments and one example from [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/), I have done the following code. There is some problems. How can I fix them ?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

    \tikzstyle{frame} = [
        rectangle, draw, 
        text width=2em, text centered,
        minimum height=4em
    ]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm]
    \node [frame] (pop) {Population};
    \node [above of=pop, left of=pop] (init) {Initialisation};
    \node [below of=pop, left of=pop] (term) {Termination};
    \node [frame, above of=pop, right of=pop] (parents)  {Parents};
    \node [frame, below of=pop, right of=pop] (off)  {Offspring};

    \path [line] (parents) -- node[right,pos=.4] {Recombination} node[right,pos=.6] {Mutation} (off);
    \path [line] (init) |- (pop);
    \path [line] (pop) -| (term);
    \path [line] (off) -| node[below,pos=.25] {Survivor selection}(pop);
    \path [line] (pop) |- node[above,pos=.75] {Parents selection} (parents);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is my huggly output !

[image]

Comment: TikZ: five nodes and five edges with four nodes attached to them.

Comment: How can I place text near edges ?

Comment: For example: `\draw[nodes=right] (Parents) edge node[pos=.33] {Recombination} node[pos=.67] {Mutation} (Offspring);` Or `\draw (Population) |- node[above,pos=.75] {Parent selection} (Parents);` And the `arrows` library provides a few arrow styles (e.g. `-triangle 45`). Nodes not attached to the liens can be placed either manually or with the help of the `positioning` library.

Comment: Take a [look](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/), have a try.

Comment: That is the meaning of my question. I've updated it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've made a couple of adjustments to the text width and node distance settings in your examples, have got to something which is nearly there, but you might want to make the arrowheads bigger?

I made the updates online using [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com), see here:

https://www.writelatex.com/37459xjfzxh

Screenshot attached[image: Original wL screenshot]
Update: Thanks to whoever made the edits to the wL document, they reached the updated image shown below, which is pretty close to the desired result [image: Updated wL screenshot]

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,positioning}

\tikzset{
  frame/.style={
    rectangle, draw, 
    text width=6em, text centered,
    minimum height=4em,drop shadow,fill=lime!40,
    rounded corners,
  },
  line/.style={
    draw, -latex',rounded corners=3mm,
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small\sffamily\bfseries,very thick,node distance = 4cm]
\node [frame] (pop) {Population};
\node [above=2cm, left of=pop] (init) {Initialisation};
\node [below=2cm, left of=pop] (term) {Termination};
\node [frame, above=2cm, right of=pop] (parents)  {Parents};
\node [frame, below=2cm, right of=pop] (off)  {Offspring};

\path [line] (parents)
 -- node[right,align=left,pos=.5] {Recombination\\[3mm]Mutation}
 (off);
\path [line] (init) |- (pop.170);
\path [line] (pop.190) -| (term);
\path [line] (off) -| node[below,pos=.25, align=center] {Survivor\\ selection}(pop);
\path [line] (pop) |- node[above,pos=.75, align=center] {Parents\\ selection}(parents);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Updated screenshot]

Comment: PS: If someone can improve this, please feel free to edit the wL doc.

Comment: PPS: This is amazing - I'm now watching someone who clearly knows what they're doing editing the wL doc & making improvements...it's quite hypnotising!

Comment: Instead of screenshots and a link to a _rolling_ code, you should include the code itself...

Comment: @JohnHammersley: Hello, thanks for the secund pretty output BUT there is two things to ameliorate. First, the arrows from/to INITIALISATION and TERMINATION overlap each other. That's not wanted (see the first picture in my question). Secundly, a lot of vertical space is wasted. Is there a way to use less vertical space ? Just one last question. Is there a way to add a backreturn so as to put "Parents" above "selection" (see the arrows from POPULATION to PARENTS).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks for the pointer, I'm still learning here so will remember to post the code in future.

Comment: @projetmbc Thanks for the extra comments - and I see that someone has already made most of the changes you asked for (thanks). To adjust the vertical space between nodes you can pass a length to the `above` & `below` commands, such as `below=1cm`. This should hopefully let you tailor the spacing to your preference.

Comment: @JohnHammersley One last thing. Is it possible to use less vertical space ?

Comment: @projetmbc See updated code & final screenshot in the answer - by including the `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` package you can specify lengths to the above and below commands. I used `above=2cm` and `below=2cm` to achieve the look in the screenshot; you can adjust as desired. Hope this helps!