# Help to reproduce a diagram in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: mdp]

This is what I have done so far:

[image: mdp_1]

This is the code to reproduce my image. I was inspired by this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95119/89662):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,positioning}

\tikzset{
  frame/.style={
    rectangle, draw,
    text width=6em, text centered,
    minimum height=4em,drop shadow,fill=white,
    rounded corners,
  },
  line/.style={
    draw, -latex',rounded corners=3mm,
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small\sffamily\bfseries,very thick,node distance = 4cm]
\node [frame] (agent) {Agent};
\node [below right of=agent] (aer) {};
\node [below left of=agent] (ael) {};
\node [frame, below left of=aer] (environment) {Environment};

\path [line] (agent)
  -| node[right, pos=1, align=left] {action\\ $A_t$} (aer)
  |- (environment);
\path [line] (environment.170)
  -| node[right, pos=1, align=left] {reward\\ $R_t$} (ael)
  |- (agent.190);
\path [line] (environment.190)
  -| node[left, pos=1, align=right] {state\\ $s_t$} (ael)
  |- (agent.170);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

I don't want a perfect result. I'm interested in maintaining the reward of state and reward separated and I don't want that blank space at the center of each path. Maybe a better way to start/end paths would be appreciated: currently, it's done with an angle but I don't know which is the actual distance between lines.

---

This is how I modified marmot's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461318/89662) to have the same distance between state and reward lines both horizontally and vertically.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows,positioning}

\tikzset{
  frame/.style={
    rectangle, draw,
    text width=6em, text centered,
    minimum height=4em,drop shadow,fill=white,
    rounded corners,
  },
  line/.style={
    draw, -{Latex},rounded corners=3mm,
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small\sffamily\bfseries,very thick,node distance = 4cm]
\node [frame] (agent) {Agent};
\node [frame, below=1.2cm of agent] (environment) {Environment};
\draw[line] (agent) -- ++ (3.5,0) |- (environment)
node[right,pos=0.25,align=left] {action\\ $A_t$};
\coordinate[left=8mm of environment] (P);
\coordinate[above=3mm of environment.west] (ENW);
\coordinate[below=3mm of environment.west] (ESW);
\coordinate[above=3mm of agent.west] (ANW);
\coordinate[below=3mm of agent.west] (ASW);
\draw[thin,dashed] (P|-environment.north) -- (P|-environment.south);
\draw[line] (ESW) -- (P |- ESW)
node[midway,above]{$S_{i+1}$};
\draw[line,thick] (ENW) -- (P |- ENW)
node[midway,above]{$R_{i+1}$};
\draw[line] (P |- ESW) -- ++ (-1.4,0) |- (ANW)
node[left, pos=0.25, align=right] {state\\ $s_t$};
\draw[line,thick] (P |- ENW) -- ++ (-0.8,0) |- (ASW)
node[right,pos=0.25,align=left] {reward\\ $R_t$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result.

[image: mdp_3]

This is already the visual result that I wanted to achieve. The question is if I could have avoided to define four new coordinates (ASW,ANW,ESW,ENW).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were loading but not using the positioning library, that is instead of `right of=`, say, please use `right=of` or `right=5mm of`. And one can kick out several auxiliary nodes/coordinates like `(ael)` and `(aer)`, they are not at all needed.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows,positioning}

\tikzset{
  frame/.style={
    rectangle, draw,
    text width=6em, text centered,
    minimum height=4em,drop shadow,fill=white,
    rounded corners,
  },
  line/.style={
    draw, -{Latex},rounded corners=3mm,
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small\sffamily\bfseries,very thick,node distance = 4cm]
\node [frame] (agent) {Agent};
\node [frame, below=1.2cm of agent] (environment) {Environment};
\draw[line] (environment) -- ++ (3.5,0) |- (agent) 
node[right,pos=0.25,align=left] {action\\ $A_t$};
\coordinate[left=8mm of environment] (P);
\draw[thin,dashed] (P|-environment.north) -- (P|-environment.south);
\draw[line] (environment.200) -- (P |- environment.200)
node[midway,above]{$S_{i+1}$};
\draw[line,thick] (environment.160) -- (P |- environment.160)
node[midway,above]{$R_{i+1}$};
\draw[line] (P |- environment.200) -- ++ (-1.4,0) |- (agent.160)
node[left, pos=0.25, align=right] {state\\ $s_t$};
\draw[line,thick] (P |- environment.160) -- ++ (-0.8,0) |- (agent.200)
node[right,pos=0.25,align=left] {reward\\ $R_t$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: If you want to adjust the distances of the two lines, there is no need to introduce new coordinat (However, your way to achieve this with additional coordinates is very elegant, I think. Just in the original question the coordinates `(ael)` and `(aer)` were not necessarily a good choice as they interrupted paths. In principle one could avoid introducing `P` in the following by switching to `decorations.markings`, but this might be an overkill.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows,positioning}

\tikzset{
  frame/.style={
    rectangle, draw,
    text width=6em, text centered,
    minimum height=4em,drop shadow,fill=white,
    rounded corners,
  },
  line/.style={
    draw, -{Latex},rounded corners=3mm,
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small\sffamily\bfseries,very thick,node distance = 4cm]
\node [frame] (agent) {Agent};
\node [frame, below=1.2cm of agent] (environment) {Environment};
\draw[line] (environment) -- ++ (3.5,0) |- (agent) 
node[right,pos=0.25,align=left] {action\\ $A_t$};
\coordinate[left=12mm of environment] (P);
\draw[thin,dashed] (P|-environment.north) -- (P|-environment.south);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ldist}{4mm}
\draw[line] ([yshift=-\Ldist]environment.west) -- 
([yshift=-\Ldist]environment.west -| P) node[midway,above]{$S_{i+1}$};
\draw[line,thick] ([yshift=\Ldist]environment.west) -- ([yshift=\Ldist]environment.west
-|P) node[midway,above]{$R_{i+1}$};
\draw[line] ([yshift=-\Ldist]environment.west -| P) -- ++ (-12mm-\Ldist,0) |- 
([yshift=\Ldist]agent.west) node[left, pos=0.25, align=right] {state\\ $S_t$};
\draw[line,thick] ([yshift=\Ldist]environment.west -| P) -- ++ (-12mm+\Ldist,0) 
|- ([yshift=-\Ldist]agent.west) node[right,pos=0.25,align=left] {reward\\ $R_t$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, this is so good that I've almost scared to ask for more but I feel brave today. Could I set in some way the offset of the state and reward arrows with respect to environment and agent? I mean without angles but with cartesian offset. Or should I simply use more `\coordinate`s?

Comment: @gvgramazio I'm sorry, I do not understand. Do you want to move the dashed line around? If yes, just change `\coordinate[left=8mm of environment] (P);` to `\coordinate[left=12mm of environment] (P);`, say. If you want something else, could you please try to reword your request a bit?

Comment: My bad. The horizontal space between state and reward lines is 0.6 because is 1.4-0.8. The vertical space between state and reward lines is determined through an angle (200 and 160). How could I set the vertical space directly?

Comment: I added an example with just a little modification to your answer achieving what I wanted. The question is if I could avoid defining 4 new coordinates.

Comment: @gvgramazio I added something that does not introduce new coordinates. Introducing auxiliary coordinates is, however, IMHO not a bad thing.

Comment: I thought that introducing new coordinates should be avoided because of an increase in computational time.

Comment: @gvgramazio I guess that the additional time due to additional coordinates is tiny, but of course you are right in principle.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the blank spaces in the middle by declaring `(ael)` and `(aer)` as `\coordinate`.

Currently Reward and State are same node in the question. Shift the State node left to get some separation between them. This can be done with `positioning` library:

```
\coordinate [left=1cm of ael] (aell) {}
```

Note that I have used `left=1cm of ael` not `left of=`. As @marmot mentioned, writing `left of=` is not using the loaded library `positioning`. This can reduce the number of nodes required also.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,positioning}

\tikzset{
  frame/.style={
    rectangle, draw,
    text width=6em, text centered,
    minimum height=4em,drop shadow,fill=white,
    rounded corners,
  },
  line/.style={
    draw, -latex',rounded corners=3mm,
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small\sffamily\bfseries,very thick,node distance = 2cm]
\node [frame] (agent) {Agent};
\coordinate [below right=of agent] (aer) {};
\coordinate [below left=of agent] (ael) {};
\coordinate [left=0.9 cm of ael] (aell) {};
\node [frame, below left=of aer] (environment) {Environment};

\path [line] (agent) -| node[right, pos=1,align=left] {action\\ $A_t$} (aer) |- (environment);
\path [line] (environment.160) -| node[right,pos=1,align=left] {reward\\ $R_t$} (ael) |- (agent.200);
\path [line] (environment.200) -| node[left,pos=1,align=right]  {state\\ $S_t$} (aell) |- (agent.160);

\draw[-latex] (environment.160) -- ++(-1,0) node[above,midway]{$R_{i+1}$} coordinate(c1);
\draw[-latex] (environment.200) -- ++(-1,0) node[above,midway]{$S_{i+1}$} coordinate(c2);
\draw[dashed,shorten >=-3mm,shorten <=-3mm] (c1) -- (c2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be worthwhile to point out that in your update you also switched to the `positioning` syntax.